# Is it possible to insert a selectonemenu (PrimeFaces) value with manual data into a column?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a small project, with a single table, and I need a certain column to acquire its value through a selectonemenu of primefaces.

As I said before, I have a single table, and the values of the selectonemenu are not preloaded as in other projects through a list, I create them in this way:

```
        <p:dialog id="dlgListas" widgetVar="dialogoListas" modal="true" closable="false" closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false"
                  draggable="true" visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
            <p:ajax event="close" update="dlgListas"/>
            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Registrar Lista"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="opcionLista" value="#{vot.lista}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar Lista" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lista 1" itemValue="1"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lista 2" itemValue="2"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lista 3" itemValue="3"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" immediate="true" onclick="PF('dialogoListas').hide();"/>
            </div>
        </p:dialog>
```

The problem I'm running into is how to pass the selected value to the BeanController.
I have tried with the line "<p:selectOneMenu id="listoption" value="#{vot.list}">", where {vot.list} is the column of the table where I need to enter the value.

I hope someone can give me a hand.

Cheers!

Gustavo

---

### ---- E D I T

I was able to fix it.
In an oversight, I did not save in the Controller Bean the value of the register that I was processing, for example:

```
public void read(Delegado delegadoSeleccionado){
    votante = delegadoSeleccionado;
}
   

public void modify(){
    votanteEJB.edit(votante);
}
```

This way, I was able to call the "modify()" method from the page:

```
<p:dialog id="dlgListas" widgetVar="dialogoListas" modal="true" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false"
                  draggable="true" visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" header="Registrar Lista">
            <!-- <p:ajax event="close" update="dlgListas"/> -->
            <!--<div class="field col-12 md:col-4"> -->
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel for="opcionLista" value="Registrar Lista"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="opcionLista" value="#{delegadoController.votante.lista}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccionar Lista" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Lista 1"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Lista 2"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Lista 3"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" actionListener="#{delegadoController.modify()}" onclick="PF('dialogoListas').hide();"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <!--</div>-->
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @JasperdeVries Hi. Jasper, I have a table to which I need to give a value to a column through a selectOneMenu of Primefaces, but this value does not come from any other table, they are values that I determine manually.

Comment: Still not making sense to me. Please add the table